# Get coefficients from locfit model

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

I have fitted data with local regression through the package "locfit" and I would like to get the coefficients, but I have not been able to get them.
I have run the function "locfit" with ev=none(), because I want a semiparametric fitting. 
I have got the fitted and residuals values, but not the coefficients. I know I could use another package, but this one works very well with this kind of curve fitting.

For instance:

```
> x
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5
> y
 [1]  5  3 25 30 40
> model=locfit(x~y,ev=none())
> fitted(model)
 [1] 1.573481 1.488706 3.119822 3.704870 5.113120
> residuals(model)
 [1] -0.5734813  0.5112941 -0.1198224  0.2951299 -0.1131203
> coefficients(model)
 NULL
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this issue. Regards.

Comment: Eventually you can explore the object `model`: `str(model)` and dive into it: `model$...`

Comment: Thank you, I have tried "model$coef", but it doesn't work.

Comment: Eventually explore the result from summary(), i.e. `str(summary(model))`

Comment: Thanks again, but the coefficients do not appear